# JMSPaymentPaypalBundle blank order summary

Tags: symfony, paypal

hi i was wondering on how to show order summary in paypal with JMSPaymentPaypalBundle ?!

ay tips will be greatly appreciated ..

here is my paypalController code in case needed

```
<?php
namespace Splurgin\EventsBundle\Controller;

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\Payment;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\PluginController\Result;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Plugin\Exception\ActionRequiredException;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Plugin\Exception\Action\VisitUrl;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;


class PaymentController
{
    /** @DI\Inject */
    private $request;

    /** @DI\Inject */
    private $router;

    /** @DI\Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager") */
    private $em;

    /** @DI\Inject("payment.plugin_controller") */
    private $ppc;
   /**
     * @DI\Inject("service_container")
     *
     */
    private $container;
    /**
     * @Template
     */
    public function detailsAction($package)
    {
        // note this ticket at this point in inactive ...
        $order = $this->container->get('ticket')->generateTicket($package);
        $order = $this->em->getRepository('SplurginEventsBundle:SplurginEventTickets')->find($order);
        $packageId = $order->getPackageId();
        $package = $this->em->getRepository('SplurginEventsBundle:SplurginEventPackages')->find($package);
        $price = $package->getPrice();
        var_dump($price);
        if($price == null){
            throw new \RuntimeException('Package was not found: '.$result->getReasonCode());
        }

        $form = $this->getFormFactory()->create('jms_choose_payment_method', null, array(
            'amount'   => $price,
            'currency' => 'USD',
            'default_method' => 'payment_paypal', // Optional
            'predefined_data' => array(
                'paypal_express_checkout' => array(
                    'return_url' => $this->router->generate('payment_complete', array(
                        'order' => $order->getId(),
                    ), true),
                    'cancel_url' => $this->router->generate('payment_cancel', array(
                        'order' => $order->getId(),
                    ), true)
                ),
            ),
        ));

        if ('POST' === $this->request->getMethod()) {
            $form->bindRequest($this->request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $this->ppc->createPaymentInstruction($instruction = $form->getData());

                $order->setPaymentInstruction($instruction);
                $this->em->persist($order);
                $this->em->flush($order);

                return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('payment_complete', array(
                    'order' => $order->getId(),
                )));
            }
        }
        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'order'=>$order->getId(),
        );
    }


    /** @DI\LookupMethod("form.factory") */
    protected function getFormFactory() { }



    /**
     */
    public function completeAction($order)
    {
        $order = $this->em->getRepository('SplurginEventsBundle:SplurginEventTickets')->find($order);

        $instruction = $order->getPaymentInstruction();
        if (null === $pendingTransaction = $instruction->getPendingTransaction()) {
            $payment = $this->ppc->createPayment($instruction->getId(), $instruction->getAmount() - $instruction->getDepositedAmount());
        } else {
            $payment = $pendingTransaction->getPayment();
        }

        $result = $this->ppc->approveAndDeposit($payment->getId(), $payment->getTargetAmount());
        if (Result::STATUS_PENDING === $result->getStatus()) {
            $ex = $result->getPluginException();

            if ($ex instanceof ActionRequiredException) {
                $action = $ex->getAction();

                if ($action instanceof VisitUrl) {
                    return new RedirectResponse($action->getUrl());
                }

                throw $ex;
            }
        } else if (Result::STATUS_SUCCESS !== $result->getStatus()) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Transaction was not successful: '.$result->getReasonCode());
        }

    }

     public function cancelAction($order)
    {
        die('cancel the payment');
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you injecting the whole container if you already inject your dependencies one by one ( em, ... ) ?

Comment: lol , im still working on the code .. it's just and old variable .. i will re-factor the code when im done

Comment: what shall be shown in your order summary ?

Comment: @nifr im really not too sure about the exact stuff , but for example , product-name and some description ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i really dont know why this is not a part of the docs , but the bundle is capable of setting checkout parameters out of the box ...

here is how i have done it

```
$form = $this->getFormFactory()->create('jms_choose_payment_method', null, array(
    'amount'   => $price,
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'default_method' => 'payment_paypal', // Optional
    'predefined_data' => array(
        'paypal_express_checkout' => array(
            'return_url' => $this->router->generate('payment_complete', array(
                'order' => $order->getId(),
            ), true),
            'cancel_url' => $this->router->generate('payment_cancel', array(
                'order' => $order->getId(),
            ), true),
            'checkout_params' => array(
                'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => 'event',
                'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => 'some event that the user is trying to buy',
                'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'=> 6.00, // if you get 10413 , then visit the api errors documentation , this number should be the total amount (usually the same as the price )
                // 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0'=> 'Digital',
            ),
        ),

    ),

));
```

error code can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/)

SetExpressCheckout Request Fields [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)

i will provide a pull request to the documentation as soon as i can .. :)

Comment: At last I found the right answer!!! I was looking this very long time and I didn't find anything. Thank you so much!!!